# \echo is not working in heredoc pased to psql

Tags: postgresql, shell

Here is my sh file.

```
SCRIPT_DIR=`dirname $0`
export DATA_DIR=${SCRIPT_DIR}/data
export SQL_DIR=${SCRIPT_DIR}/sql
FILE_NAME=${DATA_DIR}/master_exec_alert_mails.dat


if [ ! -d $DATA_DIR ]
then
    mkdir $DATA_DIR
fi

cd $SCRIPT_DIR

psql postgresql://xxxxx:xx@192.168.1.116:5432/xx   -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 << EOF > /dev/null

\o  MASTER_EXECUTIVE_EFFORT_FILE_NAME
select to_char(LOCALTIMESTAMP-INTERVAL '8 DAY','Mon dd, yyyy') || ' - ' || to_char(LOCALTIMESTAMP-INTERVAL '2 DAY','Mon dd, yyyy') 
\echo 'Master Exec effort list:'
\i master_exec_effort.sql
EOF
```

But it is not printing the message **'Master Exec effort list:'** in the **master_exec_alert_mails.dat** output file.

Can anyone explain why it is not printing ?

Comment: Probably its because "_\o [FILE]              send all **query results** to file or |pipe_". Instead of `\echo` try : "_\qecho [STRING]        write string to query output stream (see \o)_"

Comment: yes.got it.please post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer from  **Abelisto**

Probably its because "\o [FILE] send all query results to file or |pipe". Instead of \echo try : **"\qecho [STRING]** write string to query output stream